# How to make the code scaleable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There are three divas, but I plan to increase their number, but for this, the code needs to be made scalable, which it is not now.
Inside each diva there is a button that calls another Maps component and only one Maps must be open at the same time.

Here's the code, but how can it be done so that you can easily increase the number of div ??

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Maps from '../components/map'
import data from '../assets/data'
import './App.scss'

export default class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showMap1: false, showMap1Value: "Open map", showMap2: false, showMap2Value: "Open map", showMap3: false, showMap3Value: "Open map" }
    this.onClick1 = this.onClick1.bind(this)
    this.onClick2 = this.onClick2.bind(this)
    this.onClick3 = this.onClick3.bind(this)
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)

}

onClick1() {
    if (this.state.showMap1 == true) {
        this.setState({showMap1: false, showMap1Value:"Open map"})

    }

    if (this.state.showMap1 ==false) {
        this.setState({showMap1: true, showMap2: false, showMap3: false, showMap1Value:"Close map"})
    }
}

onClick2() {
    if (this.state.showMap2 == true) {
        this.setState({showMap2: false, showMap2Value:"Open map"})
    }

    if ( this.state.showMap2 ==false) {
        this.setState({showMap2: true, showMap1: false, showMap3: false, showMap2Value:"Close map"})
    }
}

onClick3() {
    if (this.state.showMap3 == true) {
        this.setState({showMap3: false, showMap3Value:"Open map"})
    }

    if (this.state.showMap3 ==false) {
        this.setState({showMap3: true, showMap1: false, showMap2: false, showMap3Value:"Close map"})
    }
}

onClick() {

}

render() {

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div>
                <h1>{data[0][0]}</h1>
                <p>
                    {data[0][1]}
                </p>
                <input type="button" value={this.state.showMap1Value} onClick={this.onClick1} />

                <div>
                    { this.state.showMap1 ? <Maps item="0"/> : null }
                </div>

            </div>
            <div>
                <h1>{data[1][0]}</h1>
                <p>
                    {data[1][1]}
                </p>
                <input type="button" value={this.state.showMap2Value} onClick={this.onClick2}  />
                <div>
                    { this.state.showMap2 ? <Maps item="1"/> : null }
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <h1>{data[2][0]}</h1>
                <p>
                    {data[2][1]}
                </p>
                <input type="button" value={this.state.showMap3Value} onClick={this.onClick3} />

                <div>
                    { this.state.showMap3 ? <Maps item="2" /> : null }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: There are these wonderful things called arrays in programming languages. They're made specifically for storing multiple items, and they're quite easy to loop through.

Comment: *"There are three divas..."* Well, there [were](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Three_Tenors), but sadly one of them has since passed on. More: ["diva" in Merriam-Webster's online dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diva)

Comment: And yes, I wouldn't have put it quite the way it's been put above, but you'll want an array for this. So that's where to continue your research.

Comment: I don't think he's made a bad choice with an object. In fact they're often more performant. The big thing when working with objects like this as a looking is to remember key names are strings, so you can subscript / access them rather dynamically of the names are well structured like they are here: `showMapX` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to store your maps in an array within state, then keep track of which map you're working using an index.

```
 class App extends Component {
   constructor() {
     super();
     this.state = {
       maps: [
        { showing: false, value: "Open map" },
        { showing: false, value: "Open map" },
        { showing: false, value: "Open map" }
       ]
     };
   }

   onClick(index) {
     if (this.state.maps[index].showing) {
       // Open the map at this index
     } else {
       // Close the map at this index
     }
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <div className="app">
         {this.state.maps.map((map, index) => (
           <div>
             <h1>{data[index][0]}</h1>
             <p>{data[index][1]}</p>
             <input type="button" value={map.value} onClick={e => this.onClick(index)} />
             <div>{map.showing && <Maps item={index} />}</div>
           </div>
         })}
       </div>
     )
   }
 }
```